# What is the point of the pull-up resistors for rows on this schematic?

Tags: schematics, pullup

I am looking through a [schematic of a keyboard](https://github.com/century-synthetics/hybris/blob/master/schematics/Hybris.PDF). It for some reason has pull-up resistors on row lines. Meantime the firmware it uses suppose to iterate over rows by bringing them up from the ICs own GPIO pins.

Wouldn't having pull-up resistors here defeat that logic by having those lines always high which in turn would cause issues with keyboard?

Comment: Post snippet of schematic's area of interest so if the link breaks this question does not become meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense to me. The MCU column pin selects the column by driving it LO, and scans the row pins. If a button in the selected column is pressed it connects the row to the column and the row pull up gets overridden by the LO column line. You're saying the firmware doesn't do this?

Comment: The keyboard uses 74HC parallel-to-serial on columns, so it cannot drive columns. There is a pull-down on columns as well as a shottky for each key, which would prevent that as far as I understand.

Comment: @AlexeyKamenskiy Isn't the shifter just to save MCU pins since you never drive more than one column at a time anyways? I think wake sense is HI or  high impedance in normal operation so the schottkys are dead ends which  don't go anywhere.

Comment: But you can't push data through shifter (at least the ones used here). It is parallel-to-serial, not serial-to-parallel. Unless MCU does drive columns, but default state is high and MCU drives them low to bring keys pressed to low as well (from default high). But that seems as a waste of power to me (and that matters since this is battery powered device).

Comment: @AlexeyKamenskiy Hmmm I think I sort of see what you mean. It looks like the shifters read the lines rather than drive it.

Comment: Looking over the schematic, I think it supposed to work in combination with wakeup pin (for when MCU goes to low power state). Then (when MCU sleeps), closing circuit supposed to drive wake_sense line high (which should bring the MCU back from sleep).

Comment: @AlexeyKamenskiy Yeah that seems plausible why the row pullups and column pulldows are there. One being 1K and the other 10K implies they are meant to work together.

Comment: @AlexeyKamenskiy You should self answer and just describe how everything works from row driving to column shift register reading.